# PHP MySQL possibly syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I don't know why but I'm getting error at this line: `$row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)){`
Here is the code:

```
<div class='topnav'> <!--Start of the Top Navigation-->
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

$select_games = "SELECT * FROM games";

$run_games = mysql_query($select_games);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)){

$game_category = $row['game_category'];

?>

<!--some links here with the variable of "game_category"-->
<?php } ?>
</div> <!--End of the Top Navigation-->
```

Please help me :(

Comment: I will try to explain better, I created a system that I upload a new game to my website and one of the parameters are "game_category", after the game has been uploaded, its now siting inside MySQL with the "game_category" of for example: "action" (action games). so now when its ready I want to display that game the "Action Games" page which is a categories.php file that generating results of games according to their category... but Im trying to use this navbar to link the results... any suggestions?

Comment: LOL! I finally solved it, I didn't need any php in my navbar.php at all... I used already a script of php in categories.php to filter me results by game_category, so I just did in every link on the navbar this: `<li><a href="categories.php?genre=action">the game category</a></li>`.
Thanks everyone ;)

Comment: Please make an answer to your own question and accept it, so it can help others too.

Comment: It wont let me, I really want to help others by my topic... I promise to submit the answer tomorrow at 1:30 AM as shown to me here...

Answer (score 0):

It should be ..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games))
{
echo $game_category = $row['game_category'];
}
```

You need to loop through the resultset !

Comment: The problem is, I don't want to use while loop, I want to include it only once...

Comment: Is your query gonna return multiple results ?

Comment: I need only to return 1 result, and its 'game_category' from PHPMYADMIN

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the result set using **while**.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)){
```

Should be

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)) {
   // do stuff  ...
}
```

Comment: I deleted my reply as soon as i saw you did.

Comment: LOL, I saw that too. Seems like we're playing "comment" delete tag haha

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a cut and paste error. The first part of your `while` loop is missing:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)){
```

should be

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)){
```

Answer (score 0):

***These functions are deprecated,so use latest ones***

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games));//if only one row
//other wise should use while
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games))
{
}
```

Comment: Its ok, I already solved it, tomorrow I will post my answer here ;)